# HTML need both js and canvas loaded in each other

Tags: javascript, html

ok. I need the canvas to load the js first, but the js needs the canvas loaded first. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>

</head>
<body>
  <center><canvas onmousemove="update_loc(event)" width="400" 
height="400" id="myCanvas" style="border: 1px solid; border-color: 
#000000"></canvas></center>
  <script src="./js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function gen_line(point1, point2) {
  var x  = point1.x;
  var y  = point1.y;
  var z  = point1.z;
  var x2 = point2.x;
  var y2 = point2.y;
  var z2 = point2.z;
  var points = [];
  if (x === x2) {
    // manual array gen
  } else {
    var slope = (z - z2) / (x - x2);
    if (slope < 0) {
      x  = point2.x;
      y  = point2.y;
      z  = point2.z;
      x2 = point1.x;
      y2 = point1.y;
      z2 = point1.z;
      var slope = (z - z2) / (x - x2);
      console.log("hi");
    }
    if (slope <= 1) {
      var z_intercept = z - slope * x;
      for (var x = x + 1; x < x2; x++) {
        points.push(new Point(x, 0, x * slope + z_intercept));
      }
    } else {
      slope = (x - x2) / (z - z2);
      var x_intercept = x - slope * z;
      for (var z = z + 1; z < z2; z++) {
        points.push(new Point(z * slope + x_intercept, 0, z));
      }
    }
  }
  return points;
}

var Face = function (a, b, c) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c;
}

Face.prototype.generate = function () {
  return this.get_lines().concat(this.get_points());
};

Face.prototype.get_lines = function () {
  var v = this.get_points();
  var points = gen_line(v[0], v[1]);
  return points;
};

Face.prototype.get_points = function () {
  return [this.a, this.b, this.c]
};

Face.prototype.draw = function() {
  var v = this.generate();
  for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    v[i].draw();
  }
};

var Point = function (x, y, z) {
  this.x = Math.round(x);
  this.y = Math.round(y);
  this.z = Math.round(z);
}

Point.prototype.draw = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(this.x * 20, this.z * 20, 20, 20);
};

var faces = [new Face(new Point(5, 0, 2), new Point(2, 0, 5), new 
Point(1, 0, 10))];

function update_loc(event) {
  faces = [new Face(new Point(Math.round(event.clientX / 20), 0, 
Math.round(event.clientY / 20), new Point(2, 0, 5), new Point(1, 0, 
10))]
}

setInterval(onTimerTick, 33); // 33 milliseconds = ~ 30 frames per sec

function onTimerTick() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  faces[0].draw();
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, i * 20);
    ctx.lineTo(400, i * 20);
  }
  for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    ctx.moveTo(i * 20, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(i * 20, 400);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

The code you should focus on is at the bottom. The rest I don't think matters, but im gonna but it in there just in case. If you have any sugestions on how to fix this, please respond. Thank you!

Comment: can you post your js file code?

Comment: The question here is **why** do you want this? I noticed that you have an `onmousemove` attribute. You can solve this racing condition by removing this attribute and listen to the event **from** your JS file: Co-dependent code typically has to wait for the page to finish loading in order to make things work. I would recommend leave the JS invocation where it is, and bind the `onmousemove` event **from** your script: `window.onload = function() {this.addEventListener('mousemove', update_loc)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to replace is this part in order to break the circular dependency

```
onmousemove="update_loc(event)"
```

You can do that by adding the event listener from JS instead of HTML like this

```
document.getElementById('myCanvas').onmousemove = update_loc
```

Ideally on page load.